# Charged object sliding off an inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coulombs-law

I was thinking of writing a physics question and this question came to my mind. Consider two identically charged objects sliding off an inclined plane of side length 4L, and the planes are identical. The angle between them and the ground is x, the coefficient of friction between objects and planes is f. Let's say *k.q.q/L2=mg.[image]*
Exactly how far would objects travel from their starting point if it released these charges from the top of the inclined planes? I have drawn the force diagram for this question, but the repulsion force acting on the side of the charges is always changing, and when this force is in equilibrium with other opposite components, the force may be zero, but the object will have a velocity, so help is needed please.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to come up with and as of now it makes sense to me unless I've made a mistake setting up some equation

[image]

Unfortunately I have no way to verify it other than the fact that the quadratic does give a solution as $lsec\theta$ which is for sure true at the very beginning of our simulation.

Also please excuse my variation of variables since it makes the problem simpler to solve and understand.

Anyone feel free to convert this to MathJax and let me know to verify any statements.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you for help. I really appreciate it